# JasperReport parameters works in iReport but fails on JasperServer with input control

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

JasperServer doesn't pass parameter from input control to the report for some unknown reason.

I defined a jrxml report with iReport 4.6 (even tried compatibility mode 4.0.1) using input parameter which works in iReport.

When I deploy the report on **jasperserver 4.5** the response I get is "The report is empty".

Same report without parameter works also well.

Naturally I defined and attached input control with single-select query.

The value column and the visible column in input control is the same DB field I use as parameter in jrxml.

Query values as possible input are displayed fine, but when I choose one..."The report is empty"!!.

I tried simplifying the report but my parameter from input control just wont be passed through to render the report.

Comment: Have you made sure that your query parameter and the input control's ID are the exact same string?

Could we see the part of your query that uses the value from the input control, and the info about the input control? (name, data type, etc)

Comment: Of course, i made sure of that - both are exactly the same strings. My query looks like this `select id, c_name from d_customers where id = $P{id}` ..Input control is pretty much straight forward `select id, c_name from d_cust`. Then I made "id" the value column and "c_name" the name column. The report is empty :-) Do you need any other input? Thanks for helping

Comment: Do you have any idea why it crashes? I've tried new instance of jasperserver, new tomcat and new Postgres DB but i am still not able to pass input parametrer without getting The report is empty!

Comment: In your JRXML file, can you display the output of your parameters? Just drag them into the JRXML file somewhere so you can see what JasperServer is actually feeding back to your query. In iReport, you might need to add the "No Data" band to your report for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the parameter in jasperserver too (not only in iReport), with same name.

In JasperServer, edit your report, define "Input controls" with same ids and go thru wizard, it should work now.

If you like to test first select "Always require in emergin window".

You can also look at the answer here http://jasperforge.org/node/543148